# Display list of changesets linked to a particular Ticket on Trac

Tags: git, plugins, trac, changeset

I have a Trac installation with the Trac-Git plugin. When committing to git, I can use TracLinks to reference to a Bug by using a prefix bug:123 or #123 and the changeset is linked to the bug. I want to achieve the reverse effect now. On a given ticket, I want to see a list of all the Changesets associated with it. I read in other threads that a post commit hook can be used. Are there any plugins that already do this? How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a template [trac-post-commit-hook](http://trac.edgewall.org/attachment/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/ComprehensiveSolution/trac-post-commit-hook) python script which adds the change comment as comment to the bugs, if they are specified on in the comment. While the script is intended for svn, it seems that git support could be simply added by changing some environment variables.

Comment: Looks like there is a fair amount of configuration that needs to be done to get it working with git. I shall get down to it. Thanks for pointing out the script.